# How to add a image on an event in android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am new to Android. In my application I want to add an process bar(an image), this should indicate that something is in process and after completion hide this precess bar.

As if i add user detail, On click on add button this process bar should be displayed.

How can i do it, please suggest.

Thanks.

**Code I used:**

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AddTicketActivity.this, "", "Loading...");

                new Thread() {

                public void run() {

                try{

                sleep(10000);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());

                }

                progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

            }.start();
```

The problem with it is , it is hardcoded `sleep(10000)` whereas what i want is it to be dependent on how much time my process takes to add or fetch data.

I am not getting where to put code which is executing on onclick of button.

I hope you got my point

Thanks again.

Comment: Looking for [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you can use either [ProgressDialog](http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/16/showing-progressdialog-in-android-activity/) or [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html).

Now, To display Progress bar and during that perform task in background, you should implement [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

1. In onPreExecute() method, display the ProgressBar or make it visible again like: **`progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`**
2. In doInBackground() method, perform the background task, i.e. add user detail in your case
3. In onPostExecute() method, just hide the ProgressBar using the **`progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`**

Comment: I am not getting how to use Async Task. as i have an activity class where i have to use this progressbar so i can not extend Async. and if i make a new private class than i have to pass some variables, than how to pass those variables in execute method.

Comment: define a seprate class and extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>, now to pass value say for example: myAsync.execute("hello"); and you can get the same as params[0] inside the AsyncTask class

Comment: but i need more variables in doInBackground method, how can i get them

Comment: @Romi more variables means Array/ArrayList, you can do this man. just look at we are getting arguments as params[] array. got it?

Comment: say as on onClick(View viewParam) method i call myAsync.execute() methood now i need this viewParam too in doInBackground() , than how to pass it

Comment: I am adding code in my question in which i used ProgressDialog, please look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you just want to show an image, you can place it on a RelativeLayout with visibility=gone

and then just control when to show or hide it.

another way is the typical [progressDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) in Android

Answer (score 0):

Or use a progress bar (spinning wheel) it's more user friendly and droid friendly .
Take a look at the Form widgets on Eclipse .

Comment: Form widgets on Eclipse means??

Comment: Double click on any layout xml file that you have on your project and then use the bottom tabs and choose : Graphical Layout .